# how to calculate CRC-32 for 24 bit long hex (for example 0xAAAAAA00)?

Tags: crc, crc32

generally, CRC-32 is being calculated for 32 bits and its multiples. i want to calculate CRC-32 for a 24-bit number. how to perform such action. I'm not from a computer science background so not having a thorough understanding of CRC-32 so kindly help.

Comment: No, a CRC-32 can be calculated on any number of bits. The _result_ is always 32 bits,  but the message you are computing the CRC over could be 1000 bits, 13 bits, 1 bit, 4891981 bits, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The actual math is in effect appending 32 zero bits to the 24 bit number when calculating a CRC. A software version emulates this by cycling the CRC as needed.

To simplify things, assume the number is stored in big endian format. Then the 24 bit value could be place into a 32 bit register, and the 32 bit register cycled 32 times (emulating appending 32 zero bits) to produce a CRC. Since after putting a 24 bit number into a 32 bit register results in 8 leading zero bits, the first step could just shift the 24 bit number left 8 bits, then cycle the CRC 24 times.

If processing a byte at a time using a table lookup and 3 bytes of data that hold the 24 bit number, the process xor's the next byte into the upper 8 bits of the 32 bit CRC register, then uses the table to emulate cycling the 32 bit CRC 8 times.

Comment: somewhat I've understood from the above answer is that I have to pad the 24-bit number with additional 32 zeroes!!!

so finally I'm putting all these values into a 32-bit register. so in the first register, I have to put this 24-bit number and 8 zeroes. in the second register, I have to write 24 remaining zeroes!!!

Comment: @ShivamChudasama - you don't need to pad. The cycling of the CRC is in effect shifting in zero bits, even though they are not in the data.